# Xpages sometimes not rendering the full html code?

Tags: lotus, lotus-domino, xpages

We're developing a document managment system with Xpages.

Sometimes rarely (I don't know when, that is what I'm trying to find out), when I open a document for editing, a bunch of controls (inputtexts, labels mostly) doesn't appear in the browser.

In the HTML source code that controls are there, but on the ui I can't see them. Then I refresh the page, and everything is ok (the HTML source code is the same when the 'bad' rendering happens).

There is no errors on the admin console, or in the log files.

Any idea what is the problem ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your browser has difficulties rendering the page. If it is in the source then XPages did its job. You might check for anything JavaScript throwing an error. Use Firebug light (if on IE) or the full if on FF.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it happen where HTML code seemed to be missing after a partial refresh.  meaning that "View Source" in the browser showed the original HTML but not the refreshed HTML.  I think when I was testing that I had to switch browsers to one that was able to refresh the original source.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Unfortunately we've still got the error.